SPFX React - How to update my breadcrumb application extension?
I have a component that is looking at the web + page context to generate a new breadcrumb. This works well except that it keeps re-adding the entire component after each page refresh/navigatedEvent. I've forced a dispose, but that just causes it to flicker in and out which isn't what I want. Do I need to pass the context.application object down the chain so I can attach an event further down the line?
My code looks like this:
public async onInit(): Promise<void> {
  setSPConfig(this.context);
  this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHoldersNav);
  this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);

  Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);    

  this._renderPlaceHolders()
  return Promise.resolve();
}
private async _renderPlaceHoldersNav() : Promise<void> {
  const sp = getLocalSPConfig(this.context);

  this._topPlaceholder?.dispose();
  this._topPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
    PlaceholderName.Top,
    { onDispose: this._onDispose }        
  );
  if(this._topPlaceholder) {
    const mainComponent : React.ReactElement<IMainComponentProps> = React.createElement(
    MainComponent, { 
      sp: sp
    });
  ReactDom.render([mainComponent], this._topPlaceholder.domElement);
 }
}

